# Why does estimate return fare_id with string 'None'?

Tags: uber-api

Got an unexpected issue in production where getting an estimate on a metered taxi product would return a fare with `fare_id='None'`. I believe this is a bug as it should return no fare or `fare_id=null`. Returning a 'None' string is very confusing and it very hacky to handle.

Sandbox does not behaves this way and return a `fare_id=null`

(using `product_id=fa89086f-ad68-45b3-a325-ca50f1e8262a`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Uber documentation `"fare_id"` is the string parameter - so values as `fare_id='None'`, `fare_id=''` or `fare_id=null` are all valid responses and should be handled by your code.